# WPF - Which built in controls implement ICommandSource?

Tags: wpf, command

That's a pretty straightforward question isn't it?

I'm just after a flat list of those controls that implement ICommandSource,..thought it would be useful and no doubt someone has that kind of info.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to reflector: `ButtonBase`, `MenuItem`, `Hyperlink` and `InputBinding` (which is not a control).

Comment: Damn, you're fast Kent.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this code snippet:

```
        Assembly assem = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\PresentationFramework.dll");
        foreach (Type t in assem.GetTypes())
        {
            Type interfaceType = t.GetInterface("ICommandSource");
            if (interfaceType != null)
                Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2009/04/14/wpf-commands-everywhere.aspx) is a good suggestion if you want to expand that all-too-short list.